# DB2 Case when need to count the digits of a value

Tags: count, db2

I need to write a case when statement in db2. I am new, so I do not have much experience,sorry for that.

I have a column with different call numbers, each call number should contain 7 digits. (eg.AR78HJ8)

I need when the value is blank or "_______", *(7 times _ )*, the result to be 0,

and when I have a seven digits call number, (but not 7 times _ ) the result to be 1.

Also , there could be cases when the call number is 8, 6 or any other different then 7 digits. In this case I want to show the call number itself.

What I have written so far is

```
    case when ab.call_number = '' then '0'
         when ab.call_number = '_______' then '0'                                                                                                       
         else '1' 
         end as "Call number",
```

but in this case I assume that all other call numbers are always 7 digits.

What should I do?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this as is:

```
WITH TAB (CALL) AS 
(
VALUES 
  '1234567'
, ''
, '       '
, 'AR78HJ8'
, '12345678'
)
SELECT CALL
, 
CASE
  WHEN CALL = '' THEN '0'
  WHEN LENGTH(TRANSLATE(CALL, '', '0123456789', '')) = 0 AND LENGTH(CALL) = 7 THEN '1'
  ELSE CALL
END AS "Call number"
FROM TAB;
```

The result is:

```
|CALL    |Call number|
|--------|-----------|
|1234567 |1          |
|        |0          |
|        |0          |
|AR78HJ8 |AR78HJ8    |
|12345678|12345678   |
```